# Location of advanced options on form

Tags: forms, checkboxes, position

In our platform, you can schedule routine scans. Imagine you can check boxes to scan for people, cars, locations. But under advanced options (located currently at the bottom) you can perform a type of scan that removes the options of cars or locations. Right now if you selected that scan under advanced options you'd see cars and location boxes go inactive.

I'm considering moving those advanced options above the check boxes, as it seems poor UX to have something that filters choices below the checkboxes you can select. Thoughts?

Comment: well, a mockup would have been extremely helpful, but if I correctly understand your description and question, then yes, you should move it above the results.